# UIScrollView scroll detection

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode, interface-builder, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` in a `UIViewController` view that scrolls horizontally. How can I detect whether the scroll is at the left end or right end or somewhere in the middle?

Answer (score 3):

You will probably need to look in to a scrollViewDelegate method such as below.

**ObjC**

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSLog(@"Point: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint(scrollView.contentOffset));
}
```

**Swift**

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    println(scrollView.contentOffset)
}
```

Have a look at the [apple docs.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate)

Also make sure to set your scrollview delegate `your_scroll_view.delegate = self;` and your view controller must conform to `<UIScrollViewDelegate>`

Answer (score 1):

GameBit is correct here, but to elaborate -

The UIScrollView has a member variable contentOffset, that describes how many pixels from the origin the scrollview has scrolled.  A positive value is a scroll to the right, negative is a scroll to the left.

Is your UIScrollView in Paged mode?   if so this will help:

```
 CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in horizontal UIScrollView

- Conform to `UIScrollViewDelegate`
- In your ViewController - `yourScrollView.delegate = self`

  ```
  func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
   var currentPage = yourScrollView.contentOffset.x / yourScrollView.bounds.size.width;
  }
  ```

Do not use `scrollViewDidScroll` as you need to wait until scrolling ends